# Install and run a program from a flash drive? 13.10

Tags: 13.10, chromebook

I'm running chrubuntu 13.10 on a Samsung Series 5 550 chromebook, And due to the limited hard drive space it's running on a 8gb partition.

I'd like to run tuxguitar off of a USB flash drive to save harddrive space. Is there any way I could do this? I have a 16gb flash drive I am happy to re-format to NTFS if that would be a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recompiled Linux releases from [TuxGuitar Project site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar).

- Download `tuxguitar-1.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz` or `tuxguitar-1.2-linux-x86.tar.gz`, depending on your system architecture from:

  http://sourceforge.net/projects/tuxguitar/files/TuxGuitar/TuxGuitar-1.2/
- Extract it in the flash disk, run `tuxguitar`